# How to prove the existence of infinitely many $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$,such that $(n^2+k)|n!$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Show there exist  infinitely many $n$ $\in \mathbb{N}$,such  that
>   $(n^2+k)|n!$ and  $k\in N$

I have a similar problem:

> Show that there are infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$,such  that
>   $$(n^2+1)|n!$$

Solution: We consider this pell equation,$n^2+1=5y^2$,and this pell equation have
$(n,y)=(2,1)$,so this equation have infinite solution$(n,y)$,and 
$2y=2\sqrt{\dfrac{n^2+1}{5}}<n$.

so $5,y,2y\in \{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$,
so $5y^2<n!$
then $(n^2+1)|n!$
 but for $k$ I have consider pell equation,But I failed,Thank you everyone can help

Comment: Why doesn't a similar method work? Use $n^2 + k = (2^2 + k) y^2$, which has solution $(2,1)$. I don't see an issue with the inequality later. $ 2y = 2\sqrt{ \frac{n^2+k} {2^2 + k} } < n$ for large enough $n>4$.

Comment: Thank you,But you must sure $n^2+k=(2^2+k)y^2$ is pell equation

Comment: The only concern I get is that $2^2+k$ is a perfect square, which it could be. Hence, I modified it slightly to make it not a perfect square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to your solution of $k=1$.

Consider the pell's equation $n^2 + k = (k^2+k) y^2$. This has solution $(n,y) = (k,1)$, hence has infinitely many solutions. Note that $k^2 + k = k(k+1) $ is never a square for $k\geq 2$, hence is a Pell's Equation of the form $n^2 - (k^2+k) y^2 = -k$.

Then, $2y = 2\sqrt{ \frac{ n^2+k} { k^2 +k } } \leq n$ (for $k \geq 2$, $n\geq 2$) always.